# Iterate through inputs in ASP.Net table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a table I create programmatically through ASP.Net code which, in each row, has a checkbox and a textfield.

What I can't seem to achieve (via jQuery at least) is to iterate all the rows to check if all rows which checkbox has been checked have text in the textfield. Confusing? Let me simplify...

I have a table. That table has 3 rows. Each row has a checkbox, some plain text and a textfield. I need to check, in jQuery, if all rows whose checkboxes have been checked by the user also have text in the respective textfields.

I tried to create a simple example based off some answers in here but this doesn't seem to be working; it displays the modal regardless of whether there is text on the input or not.

```js
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
  var hasEmpty = 0;
  $('#myTable tr').each(function(i, row) {
    var row = $(row);
    var checkbox = row.find('input[type*="checkbox"]');
    var textbox = row.find('input[type*="text"]');
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      if (textbox.val() == "") {
        hasEmpty = 1;
      };

    }
  });

  if (hasEmpty = 1) {
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="myButton">Button</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

The "dialog" part is a jQueryUI modal which I want to display when there's checkboxes that have been checked but the respective inputs don't have a value. I copy-pasted the jQueryUI example code here for the sake of simplification.
Reminder that the actual table is an ASP.Net table which is created programmatically.

Comment: `if (hasEmpty = 1) {` should be `if (hasEmpty == 1) {` - as i'm sure you know the single `=` is an assignment operator, where as `==` is used to make a comparison. Typo?

Comment: Oh snap! Seems like you're right... Typo on my original code that I was too damn stupid (so it seems) to notice... Case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're using `=` in the `if` statement, which *sets* a value, instead of `==` or `===` to *compare* values. You also don't need the additional document.ready handler around the dialog call.

With that said you can improve the logic slightly by ending the loop as soon as an invalid row is found, like this:

```js
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  if (!validateInputs())
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});

function validateInputs() {
  var valid = true;
  
  $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    var $checkbox = $row.find(':checkbox');
    var $textbox = $row.find(':text');
    
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked') && $textbox.val().trim() === "") {
      valid = false;
      return false; // break loop
    }
  });

  return valid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="myButton">Button</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Invalid" style="display: none;">
  <p>Not all checked boxes had text entries</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (hasEmpty = 1)` has single `=`. Update it as below.

```
if (hasEmpty == 1)
```

Complete code is as below.

```js
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
  var hasEmpty = 0;
  $('#myTable tr').each(function(i, row) {
    var row = $(row);
    var checkbox = row.find('input[type*="checkbox"]');
    var textbox = row.find('input[type*="text"]');
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      if (textbox.val() == "") {
        hasEmpty = 1;
      };

    }
  });

  if (hasEmpty == 1) {
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="myButton">Button</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```